# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found

Tags: r, plot, points

I'll try to keep this formatted properly and the question clear. Here's my code:

```
require(MASS)
require(splines)

graphics.off()

knots <- c(40,120)
xx <- seq(1,180,by=6)

bs.x <- bs(xx,knots=knots,degree=3)


mydata <- read.table("flux2data.txt")
class(mydata)
y1 <- t(mydata[1,])
```

(When I run the above 3 lines in the terminal, it outputs:

```
            1
V1  178.11460
V2  173.62679
V3  194.84784
V4  193.06830
V5  218.38292
V6  211.21930
V7  202.13962
V8  209.85012
V9  246.57999
V10 290.12267
V11 382.94236
V12 435.97783
V13 394.26406
V14 320.12048
V15 258.65543
V16 197.68100
V17 202.39585
V18 168.58327
V19 160.03192
V20 162.61306
V21 123.30684
V22 154.49358
V23 177.47395
V24 195.91601
V25 205.67455
V26 136.63245
V27  88.99387
V28 150.76973
V29 113.87477
V30 116.66087
```

*edited out*

```
plot(xx,y1,
     xlim=c(0,190),
     xlab="angle",ylab="y",
     main="Data")

yx <- data.frame(y = y1,x = bs.x)

bs.fit <- lm(y ~.,data=yx)

# add the fitted function to the plot
points(xx,bs.fit$fitted,pch="+",col="red")

text(0,100.23,"True function o",adj=0)
text(0,100.2,"Fitted function +",col="red",adj=0)
```

Hope that is as clear as I seem to think it is. Anyways, the error I'm running into is:

```
"Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found"
```

It plots my data just fine. It wont, however, plot a b-spline fit at I believe it should be. Any help would be awesome!

Thanks

Here is the output from dput(y1) of my data:

```
structure(c(178.114604, 173.626787, 194.847839, 193.068295, 218.382922, 
211.219296, 202.139618, 209.850119, 246.579992, 290.12267, 382.942357, 
435.977826, 394.264057, 320.12048, 258.655426, 197.680997, 202.395847, 
168.583267, 160.031924, 162.613059, 123.306841, 154.493579, 177.473953, 
195.916012, 205.674549, 136.632449, 88.993869, 150.769732, 113.874773, 
116.66087), .Dim = c(30L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("V1", "V2", 
"V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", 
"V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20", "V21", 
"V22", "V23", "V24", "V25", "V26", "V27", "V28", "V29", "V30"
), "1"))
```

Comment: your data read from file is odd you might want to consider `scan("flux2data.txt")` or `fread` from data.table to give you a cleaner read. Also post the output of `dput(sample_data)` to give people your data to play with.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I think my data being read is ok, though I could be wrong. It is a matrix of 30x60. I am (I hope) loading that as mydata, then sectioning off 1 part of it so I am left with a 1x30 set of data to plot and fit to. I'm not sure how to post the output, either... I'll try and figure that out. Thanks!

Comment: Also, thanks @Gavin Simpson for editing the format to make it look better!

Comment: given that is your `$fitted` values that are not coming up just post the output of `dput(yx)`

Comment: Sorry I am really really new to r. I typed dput(yx), and it output a large list of values. I'll put it here: > dput(yx)
structure(list(y = c(99.9970448444871, 99.9990998757803, 99.9898024659961, 
99.9884681395035, 99.998574297632, 99.9849422352998, 99.9927192782311, 
99.9852976387182, 99.9776262000363,  ......16000 more characters as numbers.... 
0.614125, 0.650962962962963, 0.68924537037037, 0.729, 0.77025462962963, 
0.813037037037037, 0.857375, 0.903296296296296, 0.950828703703704, 
1)), .Names = c("y", "x.1", "x.2", "x.3", "x.4", "x.5"), row.names = c(NA, 
-181L), class = "data.frame")